XML::LibXML: how to replace nodes with their content?
In XML::LibXML how do I replace <p>one <a>two</a> three</p> with <p>one two three<p>?
(replacing an HTML hyperlink with just its text content.)
And how do I replace <p>one <img alt="two"> three</p> with <p>one two three</p>?
(replacing an HTML image with just its ALT content.)
use XML::LibXML;
use strict;
use warnings q(all);
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => pop );
for my $p ( $dom->findnodes("//p") ) {
    for my $a ( $p->findnodes("./a") ) {
       [EMBARRASSMENT REDACTED]
    }
}

for ( $dom->findnodes("//img") ) {
    my $alt = $_->getAttribute("alt");
       [EMBARRASSMENT REDACTED]
}



OK, I figured it out. Sort of.
use XML::LibXML;
use strict;
use warnings q(all);
my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_html( location => pop );

# Well at least I stuck a <span> in its place.
for ( $dom->findnodes("//a") ) {
    my $span = XML::LibXML::Element->new("span");
    for ( $_->childNodes() ) {
        $span->appendChild($_);
    }
    $_->replaceNode($span);
}

## Might as well instead just do:
for ( $dom->findnodes("//a") ) {
    $_->setNodeName("span");
    $_->removeAttribute("href");
}

## (I never really did accomplish getting
## rid of the <a> or <span> though.)

for ( $dom->findnodes("//img") ) {
    my $alt = $_->getAttribute("alt");
    my $t   = $dom->createTextNode(" $alt ")
      ;    #blanks to avoid possible gluing to neighbors
    $_->replaceNode($t);
}
print $dom->toString();

